# How to change default ASP.NET MVC Web API media formatter?

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Web API project that returns some product data. It negotiates the return type correctly depending on the Accept header (JSON/XML) of the request. The problem is, if no Accept header is specified it returns JSON, but I want it to return XML by default. How do I change the content negotiation defaults in Global.asax?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Found a solution via http://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/

Added this in `WebApiConfig.Register()`:

```
config.Formatters.Clear();
config.Formatters.Add(new XmlMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
config.Formatters.Add(new FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter());
```

So default is XML, the first formatter, but the API still supports JSON if the request asks for it.

Comment: Also add `FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter` in your above code as by default Web API has that formatter too in the collection

Comment: what this **FormUrlEncodedMediaTypeFormatter** does?? I see that returns nothing!

Comment: @Sunny it should return URL formatted values (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.formatting.formurlencodedmediatypeformatter(v=vs.118).aspx) like `myVariable=1&myOtherVariable=test`