# ASP.NET Web API retuns XML data but I want it in JSON format

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Recently I started to work with Web API. I work ok, but I want to return data in json. It now returns records in XML. Please guide me

Comment: What you really need is answer from this question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20191980/how-to-change-default-asp-net-mvc-web-api-media-formatter

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does that by default, it return xml if you simply try your URL in the browser. There is a way to tell the api to only return json, you basically have to remove the xml serialiser and only leave in the json one:

```
configuration.Formatters.Clear();
configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

reference :

http://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/