# Why is XML response returned by default in Web API?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

When nothing is specified in "accept" header in the request, why is XML response returned by default in Web API? I mean is there anything which makes the framework to do so?

Comment: By default the accept header is set to `Accept: application/xml` that's why you get XML response by default.

Comment: If we skip the accept header, then also it returns XML.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XmlMediaTypeFormatter is the default formatter, as this is the order in which they are found in the 'Formatters' collection of the HttpConfiguration object

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20192316/1538039

You can change the behaviour here by clearing down and only adding in a Jsonformatter, e.g.

```
configuration.Formatters.Clear();
configuration.Formatters.Add(new JsonMediaTypeFormatter());
```

The [link to StrathWeb](https://www.strathweb.com/2013/06/supporting-only-json-in-asp-net-web-api-the-right-way/) contains additional information