# Set default format of web API response (ASP.NET Core)

Tags: asp.net, json, xml, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a web API in ASP.NET Core 2. I am using `FormatFilter` as defined in https://andrewlock.net/formatting-response-data-as-xml-or-json-based-on-the-url-in-asp-net-core/

I have a function defined like this:

```
[HttpGet("/api/Values/{userKey}/{variableKey}/GetValue")]
[HttpGet("/api/Values/{userKey}/{variableKey}/GetValue.{format}"), FormatFilter]
public async Task<string> GetValue(string userKey, string variableKey)
```

In Startup I have:

```
    services.AddMvc(options =>
    {
        options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("xml", "application/xml");
        options.FormatterMappings.SetMediaTypeMappingForFormat("js", "application/json");
    })
    .AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

It works fine except that I'd like the default format to be XML and not json when I call /GetValue.

I still wish to continue getting json when I call /GetValue.js and XML when I call /GetValue.xml

I cannot find any doc on how to make XML the default format.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: How are you returning results from controller's action?

Comment: The function returns a simple string, which correctly gets xml or json formatted.

Comment: maybe you can write a simple middleware that force the Accept-Content header to application/xml if the Accept.Content header is not set or doesn't contains application/json

Comment: Try clearing formaters collection and add them back in right order (first default then other). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20191980/how-to-change-default-asp-net-mvc-web-api-media-formatter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can pass a default value to a placeholder, so I changed a little the format of the URL and made it like this:

```
[HttpGet("/api/Values/{userKey}/{variableKey}/GetValue/{format=xml}"), FormatFilter]
```

Then `/GetValue` returns xml formatted

`/GetValue/xml` returns xml formatted

`/GetValue/js` returns json formatted